# File error on Android devices running QField

Tags: qfield, qgis-android

We are running Sales Force Field Service (FSL) and QField on multiple android devices.

All are running the latest app versions of FSL and QField.
There is a combination of devices from CT8 and CT8-2 rugged tablets to Samsung galaxy tablets.

The Android versions are therefore 8.1 to 10 and 11 the latest for their hardware
We have turned off MFA security in Salesforce.
In the past 2 weeks, the majority of the 20 devices no longer will autoload our usual QField zip files from the FSL/Saleforce app.   I have spoken to SF and they advise no change their side.

Whilst we can open the file from Outlook and download to a directory and then open the files successfully, the ease of use for our field technician to open the QField file from the FSL/SF app makes it much easier.

The Current Process

- The QField files are stored in SF and show up in FSL app
- The field technician clicks on the QField file in FSL and Android asks which app to open the files.
  We select the QField app.
- The system then loads the QField app and goes through its normal file loading process.
- The system then displays the navigation screen, but only with our location point but no points/data brought in.
- Their is an error log which relates to the project file saying the files don't exist (see below)
- This has only started to occur in the last 2 weeks.
- It seems to be file directory is the root cause of our issues, but I cannot work out why and how to change this across 20 devices.

The error is:

> project files "/storage/emulated/0/android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/imported database/(our file name added here).zip" does not exist

What would have caused this change?

Comment: Thanks Vince for formatting

Comment: You don't need to add "thanks" comment for formatting

Comment: If you add the zip manually to /storage/emulated/0/android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/imported database/   via Filebrowser and open it then from within QField - does it load?

Comment: if we manually download the file onto the device and then open those files from qfield they are all fine.  i must confess trying to work out how to get the qgis files into the above file/folder location (storage/emulated..)  isn't an easy task in android!  the files are working fine but the ability to select the zip folder and then ask it to open with qfield isn't .  it appears that when we open the zip folder it isn't loading/pushing the files to the right location for qfield to work.  it is starting to feel like a change in the qfield setup.

Comment: Also note a typo in the file structure above. i typed database and it should read dataset